# BigQuery Syntax Error with "("

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

**Problem**

I'm creating a query to uniformly distribute Facebook ad spend amount per ad id's.

Syntax stopped me.

```
SELECT 
t.lead_city, 
t.lead_time,
t.facebook_ad_id,
t.facebook_leadads_id,
t.id_promo,
t.value,
(d.spent / CAST((SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM `unified.FF_FACEBOOKLEADADS_DISCOUNTS_VISITS` t2 where t.facebook_ad_id = t2.facebook_ad_id) AS decimal(10,2))) as DistributedSpend
FROM `unified.FF_FACEBOOKLEADADS_DISCOUNTS_VISITS` t
INNER JOIN `unified.ads_data` d
ON d.ad_id = t.facebook_ad_id
```

This gives an error of "Expected ")" but got "(" at [24:178]". Can anyone direct to a BigQuery syntax resource or point out the mistake I'm making?

Comment: You should provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DECIMAL(10,2)` is not a valid BigQuery datatype. Try using `NUMERIC` data type instead.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types